# MySQL Bit Data Type Storage Space

Tags: mysql, types

i am studying the mysql certification guide. at the Bit Data Type section, it says

a BIT(4) sores 4 bit per value

and that storage requirement for a BIT(n) column is (n+7)/8. i dont understand this part. shldnt a BIT(4) take up just 4 bits of storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's a clumsy way to round up the result. What it means is BIT(1) to BIT(8) take 1 byte, BIT(9) to BIT(16) take 2 bytes, etc... There is no 7 bits overhead. Divide the number of bits by 8 and round up the result. BIT(4) will take 1 byte.

Comment: actually, according to excel and the mysql book formula, bit(1-4) takes 1 byte, bit(5-12) 2 bytes, bit(3-20) 3 bytes, which is quite wierd, i think the formula u mean is simply n/8 rounded up? then i think ur method makes sense, but if i were to be take the certification exam, i guess i need to follow the book? and they shld be right? unless theres an errata?

Comment: I think that "/8" is an integer division, similar to this one: SELECT (7+7) div 8;

Comment: ok then i guess that clears things up, guess computers stores btyes not bits? or rather anything using part of a byte will be rounded up?

Comment: Yes, in fact you never use bits, you always use bytes. You cannot set or retrieve a bit from the memory, you can only read/write bytes even if you only use half of it. You can read more about bits and bytes on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Comment: Josh is right. Integer divisions by default in most programming languages are the equivalent of using floor() afterwards, they simply take the integer and drop the decimals.
Therefore, 1-8 bits = 1 byte, 9-16 bits = 2 bytes, etc.

Example of this formula: (4+7)/8 = 1.375 -> floor(1.375) = 1 byte. And don't be mistaken: (7+7)/8 = 1.75 -> floor(1.75) = 1 byte!

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an overhead of 7 bits - probably identifying a block of memory as BIT storage.

This 7 bits is added to the number requestedby BIT(n) and the total is divided by 8 to give the number of bytes. *The manual defines the (n+7)/8 as BYTES*

So 4 bits requires less than 2 bytes. The manual says 'approximately' because it depends whether you talk about whole bytes or fractions.

Comment: There is no overhead other than the table structure definition. The RESULT of the formula is in bytes. However the variable n is in BITS. 1-8 bits = 1 byte storage, 9-16 bits = 2 bytes, etc.